# What to add in my code that errors processed in my Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an application written on Redux-React. In the file index.js(action) I wrote request to api, and then api gives me the answer. But one person made a remark about this code, he said:
**It is not processed at all if the API returned an error**

Small part of file index.js(action):

```
export function fetchData(day) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START", day });
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}`);
    const data = (await response.json()).body;
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: { data, day } });
  };
}
```

What to add in my code that errors processed? I'm new to web development, that is, please  demonstrate with a code.
P.S. Construction `then` cannot be used!

Comment: Put your fetch into try-catch and handle error in catch... that is it !

Comment: @Okkano demonstrate with a code, I'm new to web development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here as your request.

```
export function fetchData(day) {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START", day });
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/${day}`);
            const data = (await response.json()).body;
            dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END", payload: { data, day } });
        } catch (err) {
            // do whatever you want with the err, you can dispatch an event.
        }
    };
}
```